# insert a number greater than 10 to list in Python

Tags: python-2.7

I have a list such as `list=['a','b']`. I want to insert a number such as 1234 to list between 'a' and 'b'. When I use `list[1:1]=str(1234)` it returns `['a','1','2','3','4','b']` . I want to have out put in this mode: `['a','1234','b']`. Could you please help me?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `insert` method, which takes an index position as the first argument and the item to insert as the second:

```
In [1]: l = ['a', 'b']

In [2]: l.insert(1, 1234)

In [3]: l
Out[3]: ['a', 1234, 'b']
```

Note that `l` is the list here - you want to avoid using build-in Python keywords (such as `list`) as variable names since it will end up causing you (and others reading your code :) ) headaches down the road. As for why yours didn't work - when you assign to a slice of a list (`l[1:1]`, for example), the part on the right-hand side of the equation needs to be an iterable (i.e. something you can iterate over, like another list, a string, etc.). It then makes each element of that iterable its own element in the main list, starting at the position you specify. When you say `str(1234)`, you get `'1234'` back, which breaks down into `['1', '2', '3', '4']` when you assign it to the slice of the list.

If you wanted to accomplish the insertion using slice assignments, you could do something like this (notice how the number is wrapped in list brackets, making it a one-element list), but this is just as an example to see what is going on - `insert` has better performance:

```
In [18]: l = ['a', 'b']

In [19]: l[1:] = [1234] + l[1:]

In [20]: l
Out[20]: ['a', 1234, 'b']
```

This takes the slice of the list that starts at `'b'` and replaces it with the list `[1234]` plus the part of the original list that starts at `'b'`, which results in essentially the same thing.